# Data structure for shopping cart

Tags: data-structures

I'm working on an e-commerce application where users can add stand-alone products like *speaker* or they can add a bundle product like *desktop* that has options like *mouse, keyboard etc*. All the products and options are finally added as cart items to the cart.

For example

```
Desktop
  - Mouse
  - Keyboard
Speaker
```

After adding above the cart will have items like below,

```
Shopping Cart
  Line item 1 - Desktop - Parent-Line NULL
  Line Item 2 - Mouse - Parent-Line Item 1
  Line Item 3 - Keyboard - Parent-Line Item 1
  Line Item 4 - Speaker - Parent-Line NULL
```

If I remove the product desktop from the cart all of it's options should also be removed. At the same time we want to access all the line items as an array too.

For example,

```
for (var items in shoppingCart.items) {
  console.log(item);
}

// "Desktop", "Mouse", "Keyboard", "Speaker"
```

If I use an array to store the items then I need to work on the logic to remove the child options on removing parent. I couldn't come-up with an excellent data structure to solve this problem. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Keyboard - Parent-Line Item 1" instead of "Keyboard - Parent-Line Item 2" since item 1 is parent of Keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

A *bundle* looks a *multi set* of `options`.
The shopping cart looks a multi set of products.
Don't roll your own implementation when you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

A tree data structure is a natural way to store this data.  It supports all of the operations you listed.